# Show the chance in percentage of going over 21 in blackjack

Tags: javascript, arrays, percentage, blackjack

I have a blackjack game, where i would like it to display the odds of going above 21 and busting, relative to the remaining cards in the deck.

Something like

- Everycard drawn is removed from list
- 21 - current value of cards in hand
- From this we can say something like
- Number of cards that won't bust me = x
- Number of cards that will bust me = y
- (1 - x/y) * 100 = chance of going above 21 (busting)

But in code. this is the code till now:

```
/*jslint node: true*/
/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["log"] }] */
/*global document*/
"use strict";

var numKorttrukkede = 0;

var Spiller = {
    Kort: [],
    score: 0,
    Penge: 1000
};
var dealer = {
    Kort: [],
    score: 0
};
var deck = {
    deckArray: [],
    initialize: function () {
        var farveArray, rankArray, f, r;
        farveArray = ["&#9829", "&#9827", "&#9824", "&#9830"];
        rankArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Kn&#230gt", "Dronning", "Konge", "Es"];
        for (f = 0; f < farveArray.length; f += 1) {
            for (r = 0; r < rankArray.length; r += 1) {
                this.deckArray[f * 13 + r] = {
                    Tal: rankArray[r],
                    "Kul&#248r": farveArray[f]
                };
            }
        }
    },
    shuffle: function () {
        var temp, i, rnd;
        for (i = 0; i < this.deckArray.length; i += 1) {
            rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deckArray.length);
            temp = this.deckArray[i];
            this.deckArray[i] = this.deckArray[rnd];
            this.deckArray[rnd] = temp;
        }
    }
};

document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
deck.initialize();
deck.shuffle();

function getKortValue(a) {
    var kortarray = [],
        sum = 0,
        i = 0,
        aceCount = 0;
    kortarray = a;
    for (i; i < kortarray.length; i += 1) {
        if (kortarray[i].Tal === "Kn&#230gt" || kortarray[i].Tal === "Dronning" || kortarray[i].Tal === "Konge") {
            sum += 10;
        } else if (kortarray[i].Tal === "Es") {
            sum += 11;
            aceCount += 1;
        } else {
            sum += kortarray[i].Tal;
        }
    }
    while (aceCount > 0 && sum > 21) {
        sum -= 10;
        aceCount -= 1;
    }
    return sum;
}

function Indsats(udkom) {
    var SpillerIndsats = document.getElementById("Indsats").valueAsNumber;
    if (udkom === "win") {
        Spiller.Penge += SpillerIndsats;
    }
    if (udkom === "lose") {
        Spiller.Penge -= SpillerIndsats;
    }
}

function resetGame() {
    numKorttrukkede = 0;
    Spiller.Kort = [];
    dealer.Kort = [];
    Spiller.score = 0;
    dealer.score = 0;
    deck.initialize();
    deck.shuffle();
    document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").max = Spiller.Penge;
    document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = false;
}

function endGame() {


    if (Spiller.score === 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du vandt! Du fik blackjack." + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (Spiller.score > 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du gik over 21. Dealeren vinder!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score === 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du tabte. Dealeren fik Blackjack" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score > 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Dealeren gik over 21. Du vinder!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score > dealer.score && Spiller.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du fik mere end dealeren. Du vandt!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score < dealer.score && dealer.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du fik mindre end dealeren. Du tabte!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score === dealer.score && dealer.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du stod lige med dealeren! " + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (Spiller.Penge <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du tabte!" + "<br>" + "Du har ikke flere penge" + "<br>" + "<input type='button' value='Spil Igen' onclick='location.reload();'/>";
    }
}



function dealerDraw() {
    dealer.Kort.push(deck.deckArray[numKorttrukkede]);
    dealer.score = getKortValue(dealer.Kort);
    document.getElementById("dealer-Kort").innerHTML = "Dealer Kort: " + JSON.stringify(dealer.Kort);
    document.getElementById("dealer-score").innerHTML = "Dealer Score: " + dealer.score;
    numKorttrukkede += 1;
}

function newGame() {
    document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "";
    hit();
    hit();
    dealerDraw();
    endGame();
}

function hit() {
    Spiller.Kort.push(deck.deckArray[numKorttrukkede]);
    Spiller.score = getKortValue(Spiller.Kort);
    document.getElementById("Spiller-Kort").innerHTML = "Spiller Kort: " + JSON.stringify(Spiller.Kort);
    document.getElementById("Spiller-score").innerHTML = "Spiller Score: " + Spiller.score;
    numKorttrukkede += 1;
    if (numKorttrukkede >= 2) {
        endGame();
    }
}

function stand() {
    while (dealer.score < 17) {
        dealerDraw();
    }
    endGame();
}
```

it will all be displayed in html of course, so writing it like the score in this here

```
    <doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  margin: 30 550;
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  padding: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body class="center" style="background-color:rgb(89, 236, 255);">

     <h1> Blackjack </h1><br>

     <p> Kort: </p>

     <div id="dealer-Kort"></div>
     <br>
     <div id="Spiller-Kort"></div>
     <br>


     <form name="blackjack" onSubmit="newGame(); return false;">
     <input type='submit' id='new-game-button' value='Giv Kort'/>
     <input type='button' id='Hit-button' value='Hit' onclick='hit();' disabled/>
     <input type='button' id='stand-button' value='St&#229' onclick='stand();' disabled/>
     <br>
     <br>
     <div id=Spiller-Penge></div>


     <input type='number' id='Indsats' value='10' min='1' max="1000"/>
    </form>

     <br>
     <br>
     <p> Score: </p>
     <div id="Spiller-score"></div>
     <div id="dealer-score"></div>
     <br>
     <h2 id="message-board"></h2>
     <script src="Blackjack Spillekode.js">
     </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm kinda blank on how to do it, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Do you want the odds for drawing cards until you hit 21 or go bust?  Or do you just want the odds of busting if you draw only one card?  Or do you want the odds of busting if you continue to draw cards until you are above some specific value, such as 15?

Comment: I was thinking more in line of, what are the odds of busting, if i draw 1 more card. 

So after being give the first 2 cards, it would say the odds of busting on the next card. 
Then if i draw, and don't bust, i now have 3 cards.
I would then like it to display what the odds are of busting on the 4'th card, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach

First, check which cards are still left in the deck:

```js
const cardsInPlay = new Set(Spiller.Kort.concat(dealer.Kort));
const cardsLeft = deck.deckArray.filter(c => !cardsInPlay.has(c));
```

Then, create all possible next hands for the player:

```js
const allCombos = cardsLeft.map(c => [ ...Spiller.Kort, c ]);
```

Finally, count how many of those hands are losers and which keep you in the game:

```js
const allPossibleScores = allCombos.map(getKortValue);

const winners = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s === 21);
const losers = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s > 21);
const chances = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s < 21);

const improvementChance = 100 - Math.round(100 * losers.length / cardsLeft.length);
```

### Notes:

- I cut it up in to single `map` and `filter` steps for clarity. Of course, you can refactor this in to a single operation if you like.
- It might be worth it to add this logic to the `deck` "class" you implemented.
- I had quite some trouble reading your code because it wasn't in English... So next time you post to StackOverflow consider translating first to get a better chance of people answering.

### Running example

I added the code to your UI here so you can try it out:

```js
/*jslint node: true*/
/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["log"] }] */
/*global document*/
"use strict";

var numKorttrukkede = 0;

var Spiller = {
    Kort: [],
    score: 0,
    Penge: 1000
};
var dealer = {
    Kort: [],
    score: 0
};
var deck = {
    deckArray: [],
    initialize: function () {
        var farveArray, rankArray, f, r;
        farveArray = ["&#9829", "&#9827", "&#9824", "&#9830"];
        rankArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Kn&#230gt", "Dronning", "Konge", "Es"];
        for (f = 0; f < farveArray.length; f += 1) {
            for (r = 0; r < rankArray.length; r += 1) {
                this.deckArray[f * 13 + r] = {
                    Tal: rankArray[r],
                    "Kul&#248r": farveArray[f]
                };
            }
        }
    },
    shuffle: function () {
        var temp, i, rnd;
        for (i = 0; i < this.deckArray.length; i += 1) {
            rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deckArray.length);
            temp = this.deckArray[i];
            this.deckArray[i] = this.deckArray[rnd];
            this.deckArray[rnd] = temp;
        }
    }
};

document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
deck.initialize();
deck.shuffle();

function getKortValue(a) {
    var kortarray = [],
        sum = 0,
        i = 0,
        aceCount = 0;
    kortarray = a;
    for (i; i < kortarray.length; i += 1) {
        if (kortarray[i].Tal === "Kn&#230gt" || kortarray[i].Tal === "Dronning" || kortarray[i].Tal === "Konge") {
            sum += 10;
        } else if (kortarray[i].Tal === "Es") {
            sum += 11;
            aceCount += 1;
        } else {
            sum += kortarray[i].Tal;
        }
    }
    while (aceCount > 0 && sum > 21) {
        sum -= 10;
        aceCount -= 1;
    }
    return sum;
}

function Indsats(udkom) {
    var SpillerIndsats = document.getElementById("Indsats").valueAsNumber;
    if (udkom === "win") {
        Spiller.Penge += SpillerIndsats;
    }
    if (udkom === "lose") {
        Spiller.Penge -= SpillerIndsats;
    }
}

function resetGame() {
    numKorttrukkede = 0;
    Spiller.Kort = [];
    dealer.Kort = [];
    Spiller.score = 0;
    dealer.score = 0;
    deck.initialize();
    deck.shuffle();
    document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").max = Spiller.Penge;
    document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = false;
}

function endGame() {


    if (Spiller.score === 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du vandt! Du fik blackjack." + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (Spiller.score > 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du gik over 21. Dealeren vinder!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score === 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du tabte. Dealeren fik Blackjack" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score > 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Dealeren gik over 21. Du vinder!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage: " + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score > dealer.score && Spiller.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du fik mere end dealeren. Du vandt!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("win");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score < dealer.score && dealer.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du fik mindre end dealeren. Du tabte!" + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        Indsats("lose");
        document.getElementById("Spiller-Penge").innerHTML = "Penge tilbage:" + Spiller.Penge + "kr.-";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (dealer.score >= 17 && Spiller.score === dealer.score && dealer.score < 21) {
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du stod lige med dealeren! " + "<br>" + "Klik Giv Kort, for at spille igen.";
        resetGame();
    }
    if (Spiller.Penge <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "Du tabte!" + "<br>" + "Du har ikke flere penge" + "<br>" + "<input type='button' value='Spil Igen' onclick='location.reload();'/>";
    }
}



function dealerDraw() {
    dealer.Kort.push(deck.deckArray[numKorttrukkede]);
    dealer.score = getKortValue(dealer.Kort);
    document.getElementById("dealer-Kort").innerHTML = "Dealer Kort: " + JSON.stringify(dealer.Kort);
    document.getElementById("dealer-score").innerHTML = "Dealer Score: " + dealer.score;
    numKorttrukkede += 1;
}

function newGame() {
    document.getElementById("new-game-button").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("Hit-button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("stand-button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("Indsats").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("message-board").innerHTML = "";
    hit();
    hit();
    dealerDraw();
    endGame();
}

function hit() {
    Spiller.Kort.push(deck.deckArray[numKorttrukkede]);
    Spiller.score = getKortValue(Spiller.Kort);
    document.getElementById("Spiller-Kort").innerHTML = "Spiller Kort: " + JSON.stringify(Spiller.Kort);
    document.getElementById("Spiller-score").innerHTML = "Spiller Score: " + Spiller.score;
    numKorttrukkede += 1;
    
    // Get all cards from the deck that are not in any hand
    const cardsInPlay = new Set(Spiller.Kort.concat(dealer.Kort));
    const cardsLeft = deck.deckArray.filter(c => !cardsInPlay.has(c));
    const allCombos = cardsLeft.map(c => [ ...Spiller.Kort, c ]);
    const allPossibleScores = allCombos.map(getKortValue);

    const winners = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s === 21);
    const losers = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s > 21);
    const chances = allPossibleScores.filter(s => s < 21);

    const improvementChance = 100 - Math.round(100 * losers.length / cardsLeft.length);

    const oddsLabel = Spiller.score < 21 ? [
      `Cards left in deck: <b>${cardsLeft.length}</b>`,
      `Cards that get you to 21: <b>${winners.length}</b>`,
      `Cards that stay below 21: <b>${chances.length}</b>`,
      `Cards that loose: <b>${losers.length}</b>`,
      `Chances of improving: <b>${improvementChance}%</b>`
    ].join("\n") : "Game is over";    
    document.getElementById("Spiller-odds").innerHTML = oddsLabel;
    
    if (numKorttrukkede >= 2) {
        endGame();
    }
}

function stand() {
    while (dealer.score < 17) {
        dealerDraw();
    }
    endGame();
}
```

```html
<style>
.center {
  margin: 30 550;
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  padding: 50px;
}
</style>
 <body class="center" style="background-color:rgb(89, 236, 255);">

     <h1> Blackjack </h1><br>

     <p> Kort: </p>

     <div id="dealer-Kort"></div>
     <br>
     <div id="Spiller-Kort"></div>
     <br>


     <form name="blackjack" onSubmit="newGame(); return false;">
     <input type='submit' id='new-game-button' value='Giv Kort'/>
     <input type='button' id='Hit-button' value='Hit' onclick='hit();' disabled/>
     <input type='button' id='stand-button' value='St&#229' onclick='stand();' disabled/>
     <br>
     <br>
     <div id=Spiller-Penge></div>


     <input type='number' id='Indsats' value='10' min='1' max="1000"/>
    </form>

     <br>
     <br>
     <p> Score: </p>
     <div id="Spiller-score"></div>
     <pre id="Spiller-odds"></pre>
     <div id="dealer-score"></div>
     <br>
     <h2 id="message-board"></h2>
     <script src="Blackjack Spillekode.js">
     </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help User3297291
This was excatly what i had in mind.

Comment: And sorry, didn't think it through, ill make sure to translate it to english the next time, before i post, thank you for the help kind stranger.